# AWS SageMaker Notebook Extension Installation

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I am Using SageMaker Notebook for some deep learning tasks. However, raw SageMaker does not provide much of nbextension options such as auto complete for Hinter, not even provide a `configurator` as traditional Notebook. So, I installed `jupyter_contrib_nbextensions` and try to enable `Hinter` by `jupyter nbextension enable Hinter/main`.
However, the functionality still does not show up.
When I run `Jupyter nbextension list`, it shows like:
[image]
Can someone tell me how to successfully add and use nbextension on SageMaker Notebook?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using Studio? Also, what do you mean by raw here? I suggest using SageMaker Studio. It allows you to select from a variety of kernels that already contain required library packages for running example notebooks.

Comment: No, I am using SageMaker Notebook